# How to create an edit button in an Contextmenu in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, contextmenu, edit

to say it at the beginning - i am not a good programmer.

Im trying to create an contextmenu with an delete and edit function but im kinda having trouble with the edit function. As soon as the user is pushing the edit button in the contextmenu, he should be able to change the name of the Button i long pressed to open the contextmenu.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){


    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.Bearbeiten:
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            buttonActOne.setText(editText.getText());
            return true;
```

Of course the programm keeps crashing as soon as the user pushes the edit button and im kinda running out of ideas how i could do it else.

I really hope somebody has an good answer for me.

Edit:

Ok, first of all thanks for the answers till now. Im posting my complete MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.michl.myapplication5;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


private TextView textViewIntro;


public Button buttonActOne;
public Button buttonActTwo;
public Button buttonActThree;
public Button buttonActFour;
public Button buttonActFive;
public Button buttonActSix;
public Button buttonActSeven;
public Button buttonActEight;
public Button buttonActNine;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    textViewIntro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewIntro);


    Button ButtonActOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActOne);
    ButtonActOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seite_zwei.class));   
            Button ButtonActOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActOne);
            registerForContextMenu(ButtonActOne);


        }
    });



    Button ButtonActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActTwo);

    ButtonActTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seite_drei.class));

            Button ButtonActTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActTwo);
            registerForContextMenu(ButtonActTwo);
        }
    });

    Button ButtonActThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActThree);

    ButtonActThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seite_vier.class));

            Button ButtonActThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActThree);
            registerForContextMenu(ButtonActThree);
        }
    });
    Button ButtonActFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActFour);

    ButtonActFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seite_fuenf.class));

            Button ButtonActFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActFour);
            registerForContextMenu(ButtonActFour);
        }
    });
    Button ButtonActFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActFive);

    ButtonActFive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seite_sechs.class));

            Button ButtonActFive = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActFive);
            registerForContextMenu(ButtonActFive);
        }
    });
    Button ButtonActSix = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActSix);

    ButtonActSix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seite_sieben.class));

            Button ButtonActSix = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActSix);
            registerForContextMenu(ButtonActSix);
        }
    });
    Button ButtonActSeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActSeven);

    ButtonActSeven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seite_acht.class));

            Button ButtonActSeven = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActSeven);
            registerForContextMenu(ButtonActSeven);
        }
    });
    Button ButtonActEight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActEight);

    ButtonActEight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Seite_neun.class));

            Button ButtonActEight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonActEight);
            registerForContextMenu(ButtonActEight);
        }
    });



}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){


    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.Bearbeiten:
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            buttonActOne.setText(editText.getText());




            return true;
        case R.id.Löschen:
            return true;
            default:

    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


  }
}
```

And here is my logcat log when i start the programm and try to edit something.

```
08-28 13:52:06.135  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
08-28 13:52:06.150  26482-26488/com.example.michl.myapplication5 E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-28 13:52:06.150  26482-26488/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-28 13:52:06.290  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
08-28 13:52:06.295  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
08-28 13:52:06.295  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
08-28 13:52:06.300  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 10
    User space API version: 10
08-28 13:52:06.300  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012
08-28 13:52:06.315  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-28 13:52:17.355  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
08-28 13:52:17.355  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13334: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
08-28 13:52:17.355  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
08-28 13:52:17.360  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-28 13:52:17.360  26482-26485/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 188K, 14% free 9612K/11143K, paused 12ms+18ms, total 49ms
08-28 13:52:17.360  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 412: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-28 13:52:17.360  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-28 13:52:17.360  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-28 13:52:17.360  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 434: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-28 13:52:17.360  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-28 13:52:17.465  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-28 13:52:17.465  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-28 13:52:18.345  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-28 13:52:18.345  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
08-28 13:52:19.605  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
08-28 13:52:19.635  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 W/ResourceType﹕ Failure getting entry for 0x010802c1 (t=7 e=705) in package 0 (error -75)
08-28 13:52:20.935  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-28 13:52:20.935  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4191e2a0)
08-28 13:52:20.955  26482-26482/com.example.michl.myapplication5 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.michl.myapplication5.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:161)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2647)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3921)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:193)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:934)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3973)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 13:52:31.590  26482-26482/com.examp

le.michl.myapplication5 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 26482 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post your logcat please.

Comment: Have you initialized your 'buttonActOne'?

Comment: I updated the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your button on the onCreate method of the Activity!

```
Button buttonActOne = findViewById(R.id.buttonActOneId);
```

Then add the listener to it:

```
buttonActOne.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The setOnClickListener implements the interface View.OnClickListener, so the @override method it has to be onClick(View v), then in the switch you can use the v.getId();

In resume:

```
public class YourActivityName extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button buttonActOne;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        //set your layout
        buttonActOne = findViewById(R.id.buttonActOneId); //put the id defined in your xml layout
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (View.getId(R.id.Bearbeiten)) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            buttonActOne.setText(editText.getText());
        }
    }
}
```